# Magento 2.2.5 Category admin stuck after thumbnail image upload

Tags: magento2, admin, category, admin-panel

I've just tried to upload a thumbnail image to a category, when pressing save, the washed-out loading screen appears and never goes away.  If I back out of that page and then try and go back, the loading screen is still there.  Logging out, quitting the browsers doesn't seem to make any difference.  The category is now uneditable in the admin.

This was a migrated site, and first time I've checked thumbnails - the rest of the migration was perfect.

This is the exact issue, but no answers...
[Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function coming from file-uploader.js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224033/uncaught-typeerror-value-map-is-not-a-function-coming-from-file-uploader-js?rq=1)
Please help!

Comment: Did You try in different browsers ?
Is that any console error ?

Comment: Yes, happens in multiple browsers.  In console I get this... TypeError: value.map is not a function. (In 'value.map(this.processFile, this)', 'value.map' is undefined)

Comment: Check this link :  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138642/magento-2-1-image-not-uploading-in-edit-form

Comment: That doesn't relate.  I'm not building a custom form.  my problem is with the core category thumbnail upload.

Comment: I've updated my main post with a link to a exact problem.  Unfortunately no answers to that one!

Comment: That was me who posted the question you linked to. I still have not found the answer. I have sent this in to Magento support and they could not recreate it and said it was a browser issue. I have tried getting in for Chrome, Firefox, and Midori and still can't get in. I am now on 2.2.5 and it still happens.

Comment: Just out of interest, did you migrate an old site to Magento 2, or was it completely fresh?

Comment: I migrated from 1 to 2

Comment: Same here.  I think that's the root of the issue.

Comment: Can you get in your categories page and change anything?

Comment: I can edit categories where I haven't tried to edit the thumbnail.  On those were I have tried to edit, I get a loading screen - they are unusable. Child categories also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80711/discussion-between-tjjen-and-user2689138).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Amasty Layered Navigation. Disable that and everything will work again.