# Magento 2 : When you upload a thumbnail or category image in Magento 2 where does it go?

Tags: magento2, product-images, image, media-images, gallery-image

I am trying to find the filepath for where a category image or thumbnail goes after being uploaded in admin.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the images you normally upload go (and should go ,in case of custom modules too) in `pub/media` .

Thumbnails usually go in `pub/media/catalog/product/{product-specific-url}` , similarily the category goes in  `pub/media/catalog/category/{product-specific-url}`.

If you are wondering how specific urls are working, then it is usually like following;

For eg. gift-card-physical-custom.png is the image , then according to first two letters (**gi**ft) (usually) it makes two folders such as `pub/media/catalog/product/g/i/` and places image in that folder.This happens when we set `Files Dispersion` property for `\Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory` while uploading in magento.

Comment: I still have not figured out this issue- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224033/uncaught-typeerror-value-map-is-not-a-function-coming-from-file-uploader-js In attempting to troubleshoot that I realized I did not have a pub/media/catalog/category folder so  I created one and moved my thumbnails in there. My problem still exists. Do you think there is somewhere else they could be as well?

Comment: Sure, let me try.