# How to define data to show imageUploader UI element?

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, uicomponent, ui-form

Today I trying to create new attribute in `product_form.xml` on M2 admin.
This is code I add my field:

```
<field name="xx" formElement="imageUploader">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Image</label>
        <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <imageUploader>
            <settings>
                <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                <uploaderConfig>
                    <param xsi:type="string" name="url">my/xx/save</param>
                </uploaderConfig>
            </settings>
        </imageUploader>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

Then I used custom code to save image and it's worked, with attribute value is `"a/1/amge.jpg"`.
Now I don't know I can show image in `imageUploader` UI element. Somebody can let me know how I can this? Thanks.

The message I got is:

> TypeError: value.map is not a function in file-uploader.js

Comment: Try this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/289392/37497

Answer (score 0):

> Here my column name is **thumbnail** for image

```
<field name="thumbnail" formElement="imageUploader">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Image</label>
        <componentType>imageUploader</componentType>
    </settings>
    <formElements>
        <imageUploader>
            <settings>
                <allowedExtensions>jpg jpeg gif png</allowedExtensions>
                <maxFileSize>2097152</maxFileSize>
                <uploaderConfig>
                    <param xsi:type="string" name="url">my/xx/save</param>
                </uploaderConfig>
            </settings>
        </imageUploader>
    </formElements>
</field>
```

add this code for image show in from

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\YourModelName\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $loadedData;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $CollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $CollectionFactory->create();
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
    // @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd

    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        //Replace image with Imageuploader field name
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            if ($model->getThumbnail()) {
                $m['thumbnail'][0]['name'] = $model->getThumbnail();
                $m['thumbnail'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl() . $model->getThumbnail();
                $fullData = $this->loadedData;
                $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = array_merge($fullData[$model->getId()], $m);
            }
        }
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        /* set your path where image store */
        $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'YourFolderName/';
        return $mediaUrl;
    }

}
```